# How to represent a US state in my Django model?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, model

I'm using Django, Python 3.7.  I want to represent a US state field in my model.  So I added this

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.models import USStateField
...
class UsLocation(models.Model):
    address_1 = models.CharField(_("address"), max_length=128)
    address_2 = models.CharField(_("address cont'd"), max_length=128, blank=True)

    city = models.CharField(_("city"), max_length=64, null=False)
    state = USStateField(_("state"), null=False)
    zip_code = models.CharField(_("zip code"), max_length=10, null=False)
```

Bu tthis is resulting in an "Unresolved reference 'USStateField'" in the import line.  I'm not tied to using this library.  Is there another way I can conveniently represent a US state and if not, what's wrong with the above?

Answer (score 1):

[Per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/localflavor/), `localflavor` has been separated out into a third party library. You can follow the installation instructions [here](https://django-localflavor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation), then:

```py
from localflavor.us.models import USStateField
...
class UsLocation(models.Model):
    ...
    state = USStateField(...)
```